# Is HttpClient My Best Option to Consume an API in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am making a web app (.NET Core 3.1) and currently have an API created (using an API controller) that I want to consume in my web app (and display it's data on the View). The API is a few simple `GET` requests as following (and is working great when accessing the proper endpoints):

```
//GET: api/Fish
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<Fish> fish = _dataRepository.GetAll();
            return Ok(fish);
        }

        //GET: api/Fish/5
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(long id)
        {
            Fish fish = _dataRepository.Get(id);

            if (fish == null)
            {
                return NotFound("The fish could not be found");
            }

            return Ok(fish);
        }
```

Now, on my homepage I want to allow the user to type in an endpoint on my form, and I will return the JSON from my API. This is my form:

```
<form class="form-inline" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Endpoint">https://url.com/api/</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Try entering fish/4" asp-for="Endpoint"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GET</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    @Model.ReturnedJson
</div>
```

Here is the view model:

```
public class GetDataViewModel
    {
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }
        public string ReturnedJson { get; set; }
    }
```

And my homepage controller to get the entered endpoint, and retrieve the JSON from the API:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(GetDataViewModel model)
        {

            var url = "https://localhost:44398/api/" + model.Endpoint;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var table = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
                    model.ReturnedJson = data;
                }
            }

            return View();
    }
```

What I'm wondering, is this:
Is HttpClient my best bet to handle this? I was hoping there was a way I could just call my API methods, something like `ApiController().Get` but I don't think that is possible (at least in my research). Also, is it possible to return the RAW (preferably prettified) JSON directly on the homepage, or will I need to show it on a different view? I'm not 100% sure what my method should be returning in place of `return View()` to show that JSON data.

Edit:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(GetDataViewModel model)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:44398/api/" + model.Endpoint);
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                model.ReturnedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Those are both of my Index methods in the controller. I seem to be getting a Sustem.NullReferenceException when the web app starts up. I assume it's because my model isn't passed in on load (first Index method), but if I add it there, I get an error because it's then the same declaration as the second Index method. The following is my view:

```
@model TheFishAPI.Models.ViewModels.GetDataViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form class="form-inline" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Endpoint">https://url/api/</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Try entering fish/4" asp-for="Endpoint"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GET</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ReturnedJson))
    {
        Html.Raw(Model.ReturnedJson);
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Putting as comment because it doesn't directly answer the question: You can add your Controllers as services with DI `services.AddMvc(/*settings*/).AddControllersAsServices();`. This will then let you have your controllers passed to other ones as a service.

Comment: In answer to your question, no, it isn't the best way to handle it. What @li223 said would work but given your actual requirement, might it be better to use Ajax on the client side to get the json response and then update the DOM directly rather than doing a full post back?

Comment: Why not use redirect to proper endpoint?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Ajax would more than likely be the easiest way to go about this. I am trying to learn more about .NET though, which is why I am trying to handle this mostly in the controller. I may end up just using Ajax if I can't get it working in my controller though, thanks.

Comment: I recommend reading [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) and the [original article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). In ASP.NET Core you should definitely be using HttpClientFactory (which MS made to fix the issues mentioned in those articles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. I personally would do this one. If your api doesn’t have any Cors issue, I would call it directly using JavaScript or jquery Ajax, they also have libraries that support rest calls. This would bypass the need to go via your controllers plus it can be done in ajax manner. If you go this route you can even do this to pretty print your json:

   JSON.stringify({ uno: 1, dos: 2 }, null, '\t');
2. If all you need is to expose your api endpoints, have you looked at swagger ui? May be that’s not what you need but looking at the code you shared, seems like that’s what you are creating.
3. Http client factory is indeed better approach instead of using http client.
   Here are some of the libraries you can use to consume REST apis:

https://code-maze.com/different-ways-consume-restful-api-csharp/amp/

Pretty printing:
In c# you can do something like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.Indented);` 
to pretty print, but ensure you add it using Raw tag helper or just indent it on the view like so:

```
@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelProperty, Formatting.Indented))
```

Last for your return View, you can return the same model in which you populated the json just make sure you indent it in action or directly in view to pretty print it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(GetDataViewModel model)
        {

            var url = "https://localhost:44398/api/" + model.Endpoint;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      // deserialize first since json is your response type
 var table=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
// re serialize with formatting:
                    model.ReturnedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
    }
```

In your view do this:

```
<pre>
    @Html.Raw(Model.ReturnedJson) 
</pre>
```

Comment: Is it considered bad practice calling my own API from inside the web app? Like using the full API url to call it? That's part of why I wanted to just call the c# API `GET` method from my home controller. I will look into using `HttpClientFactory`, but I will most likely go the `AJAX` route. Thanks!

Comment: Before going the AJAX route, I do want to get `HttpClientFactory` working (learning experience). To populate the JSON data into my view (specifically the div in my question), I use `@Model.ReturnedJson`, this means in my controller, at some point after I prettify the JSON, I just need to assign it to the model property `ReturnedJson`... Would that look something like `model.ReturnedJson = prettifiedJson;`? I would then just need to `return View()` in my method?

Comment: Updated my answer to include your action and view changes.

Comment: Regarding the bad practice question, that’s not a bad practice, it’s just an option that you might choose depending on your current application design or what tech stack you are comfortable it. I don’t see anything wrong In not going via controller route. In fact I think it’s better if you don’t, because you would need to make a network call to your server to do a Http Get to your controller first then to your api and then the data comes back to your view. However in ajax you skip a network call. So in a way an ajax call is much better.

Comment: Thank you, so much. I'll be marking this as the answer as you gave me all the info I needed. The only issue I'm having is that `@Html.Raw(Model.ReturnedJson)` is giving me a `System.NullReferenceException`. I got the same error before when I was just trying to use `@Model.ReturnedJson`. This happens as the web app is loading, so I don't even get a chance to get to the homepage and try out the form. I tried making it nullable in the model (`string?`) but that didn't solve anything.

Comment: You should be able to get around it by adding an if condition in your view like @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnedJson)){@Html.Raw(model....)}

Comment: But you know a better design is that you have separate actions for initial page load and user input’s processing, that separates out the responsibility of the actions. In your case have a get action for initial page load with the same view model but returned json will be empty so keep the null check. Then create a new post action that also has a same view model that returns your response this time. If you want to simplify it further you can even have separate views.

Comment: I actually did try exactly that, no luck though. I added some more info to my question. I think it has to do with my two Index methods in the controller, and the GET one not passing in the model. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Okay that’s obvious because you are not passing the model itself so model is null not returnedjson. So either have a separate view for initial load or pass an empty model like just new it up in your get and pass it.

Comment: One thing I want you to note is that on the view you have specified @model.... so that means that view is expecting that model right ? Basically you are making it dependent on the model. That’s why I said that either have a separate view that does not depend on the model or just pass it an instance of empty model with the null check in view for returned json.

Comment: Yes, I ended up changing my return statement in the first Index method to be `return View(new GetDataViewModel());`. No errors anymore! Which is great, thanks! The JSON never appears on the view though, any idea?

Comment: I may keep the homepage as-is, and add the returned JSON to a partial view. I assume I just make the partial and add the model to it? I would need any controller action accompanying the partial?

Comment: If the model is getting populated it should be coming up. Can you add your latest view code? Yeah you can use partial as well to simplify things.. here is the documentation for adding partial views https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks for the link! I added my view to the original comment.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on return View(model) and confirm that model.ReturnedJson is populated? If yes then remove html.raw and check to see if that shows up.

Comment: Yes, it is populated. So I removed the check in the view, and just used @Model.ReturnedJson, and it works! The JSON is displayed whenever I hit submit. I just need to get it formatted properly as 'prettified' JSON, and it's all good!

Comment: Yeah now since you are passing empty view model, you won’t need the check. If you add html.Raw does it prettify it?

Comment: It doesn't. There are a bunch of slashes in the returned JSON. I assume that is coming from a certain step in the c#.

Comment: Sorry I missed one thing, html.raw needs to be <pre> tag like <pre> html.raw(...)</pre>

Comment: Thank you! That's a step in the right direction for sure. The data now appears in one long horizontal scrolling div. The data appears like `"{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Walleye\",\"scientific\":\"Sander Vitreus\", . . .` so there are still some back slashes I will need to deal with. Is it possible to format the JSON cleaner (think how JSON looks in Postman when you click the "Pretty" tab)?

Comment: @dotnetdev can you try to deserialize the json first in your action and then try serializing it again with indent format options? Reason being I think it’s getting serialized twice since your api is already returning json. So when we serialize it again without deserialize it might be getting double serialized.

Comment: That's exactly what was needed. Thanks. I'm going to update my question today showing my entire resolution to help others.

Comment: Cool I have updated my answer as well, please upvote if all is good. Thanks